# How to efficiently find parts of a string with beginning and ending specified?

Tags: programming, string-manipulation, performance-tuning

I'm trying to find specific URL addresses from a html document. The addresses can be found between the strings "href=\"" and "\" class=\"listing". The problem is not including strings like this: "href=\"############href=\"##########\" class=\"listing", where there is the beginning string in the middle of the result. The following code works, but is for some reason very very slow. It takes around 40 seconds to run the algorithm on my computer. Why is so simple an algorithm so slow?

```
#[[1]]& /@ 
  Select[ 
   ((StringCases[#, (x__ ~~ "\" class=\"listing" ~~ ___) -> x] &) /@ 
     StringSplit[theURLDocument, "href=\""]),
   UnsameQ[#, {}] &]
```

First the `StringSplit` splits the document from where there is the beginning specifying string.

Then the `StringCases` picks out the strings that contain the ending specifying string, and takes the part before it.

Finally the `Select` removes empty lists from the result (those strings that didn't contain the ending specifying string), and the pure function Mapped at the beginning of the code removes the curly brackets, made by the StringCases function, from around the elements of the result list.

Is there a way to make *Mathematica* discard the previous text when it finds the beginning specifying string again? Can I make *Mathematica* find the links with one pass through the document?

Comment: Your code does work. Thanks! The code runs in 0. seconds.

Comment: I guess finding easier to check conditions is what optimization is about, it solved my problem. But what if there wasn't any special character that doesn't appear in the correct result? The Except function only works with single characters.

Comment: When I use the StringFreeQ insted of Except, the run time jumps to over a minute. Actually the code is still running. Puzzling!